# Laravel - Inserting/Updating Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have a pivot table employee_project. In it, I have id, employee_id and project_id.

Each project has an Account Manager and a Project Manager. So in my form I have name (for the project) which should add the id to project_id and I also have am_id and pm_id, which refer to employee_id. How do I get these IDs into the pivot table since they are named differently than employee_id?

This does not work:

```
$p = Project::create($request->all());

$p->employees()->sync(['am_id', 'pm_id']);
```

What should I do differently?

**Table Structures**

```
--projects  
id  
name  
stage  
status  
timestamps

--employees  
id  
name  
department

--employee_project  
id  
employee_id  
project_id
```

Comment: Please post your table structures.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen table structures added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming doesnot matter.The values inside array are employee_id anyway. `$p->employees()->sync([1,2]);` should work.
You are passing `am_id` and `pm_id` as string?

Try with:

```
$p->employees()->sync([$request->am_id, $request->pm_id]);
```

Comment: Thanks Sanzeeb....that worked!  Didn't realize I had to do $request in front.  I thought it would pick up the itself but good to know.